# How we can find this integrate and derivation? If f(x,y)=max{ x,y}.

Tags: calculus, analysis

If $f$ is a two variable function include the $Min$ or $Max$ operator, How we can calculate integrate and derivation of this function?
For instance if:
$$f:\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $$
Such that:
$$f(x,y)=\max\lbrace x,y\rbrace $$
What is the derivation and integrate of $f$?
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,y)dxdy?$$
Or
$$f^{\prime}_{x}(x,y)?$$
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might find useful to divide the domain of the function into smaller sets where the function $f$ has an easier formulation.
For instance, the function $f$ restricted to the set $\{ (x,y) \in [0,1]^2 : y \geq x \}$ is simply the function $f(x,y) = y$.
This should help you to find the value of the integral.

The computation of the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f(x_0,y_0)}{\partial x}$ can be solved in a similar way. You only need to be careful when $x_0$ belongs to the set $\{ (x,y) \in [0,1]^2 : x = y\}$.